# Error Reading data from `Sqlite` DB

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to `SQLITE` DB
I'm using these lines of code to create DB, Table and insert, retrieve data

```
 try {
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Custom_Database", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("Create Table If Not Exists Age (FirstName Varchar, LastName Varchar, age int(3));");
    db.execSQL("Insert into Age Values ('Inzimam', 'Tariq', 22);");
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * From Age", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pName")) + " " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fName")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Created Your code is working ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    c.moveToNext();
    db.close();
}catch (Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error : " +e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

> But it throws exception Couldn't row 0, column -1 from `CursorWinsow`.
>   Make sure the cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data
>   from it.

I think `c.moveToFirst();` should do the job for that **But** its not doing why ?

How ever the same code is working in other project. What is the reason its giving the error in this app ?

**Edit:** After storing FisrtName and LastName in String and using Strings to Toast working fine as

```
String name = c.getString(0);
String father = c.getString(1);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name = " + name + " " + father, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**But** I wondering what's the difference by getting data in `Toast` or `Strings`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this way using do => while:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {   //looping through all rows
        do {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pName")) + " " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fName")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Created Your code is working ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
```

also you need to add:

```
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

before:

```
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * From Age", null);
```

Comment: By adding `db = this.getWritableDatabase();` its giving syntax error  "Couldn't resolve `getWritableDatabase();` method

Comment: try without that line and tell me where you are using this in fragment or activity